# What's the difference between tr/// and s/// when using regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I was wondering when one should use `s///` over `tr///` when working with regular expressions in Perl?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`s///` is for substitution:

```
$string =~ s/abc/123/;
```

This will replace the first "abc" found in `$string` with "123".

`tr///` is for transliteration:

```
$string =~ tr/abc/123/;
```

This will replace all occurrences of "a" within `$string` with "1", all occurrences of "b" with "2", and all occurrences of "c" with "3".

Comment: Don't forget our favorite golf putter, `y///`!

Comment: @Herdsman there's no difference between the two. It's a transliteration operator, so `tr///` was what they called it, but because `y///` does the same thing in sed, they also brought `y///` into Perl.

Comment: The main difference is it will iterate over it and change any individual matches, for example `tr/uk/gb/` will change any occurances of `us` to `gs` and any occurance of `ak` to `ab`

Answer (score 19):

`tr///` is not a regular expression operator. It is suitable (and faster than `s///`) for substitutions of one single character with another single character, or (with the `d` modifier) substituting a single character with zero characters.

`s///` should be used for anything more complicated than the narrow use cases of `tr`.

Answer (score 8):

From [perlop: Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

> Note that tr does not do regular
>   expression character classes such as
>   \d  or [:lower:]. The tr operator is
>   not equivalent to the tr(1) utility.
>   If you want to map strings between
>   lower/upper cases, see lc and uc, and
>   in general consider using the s
>   operator if you need regular
>   expressions.