# How do I map one set of letters to another set in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a dna string like

```
tcatttcaaatcatctggaccaaaagagtcaggaagtaactcttctatcgttttcatatcataacccccgt
cgtcatgaaacatataaacatttatatccttcgaaaattcacgaattacttgacgacaaataccacagggc
gtaactcttcccttggcactcatcactccaatagccataaatttagtgtaacccatgctcactgcttttgt
aattgctactcgttcggcacagatgcaattgccatatgatgcgttttcaacattagctccataaatatatg
tatttttatcgtcggatactacgcatgcacctactgcgaagttggagtagggacaatatgaatattgtaaa
ctctcttttacttcttgaaataacttctcaatatcttctttttccat
```

(except as one long strong with no breaks)

Now I want to replace all `a` to `t`, `t` to `a`, `c` to `g`, `g` to `c` how can I do using a regular expression?

Comment: Look at the Perl translation operator `tr//`

Comment: Why do you want to "do it using regular expression"? As Paul says in his comment and Steve in his answer, `tr///` is much more suitable.

Comment: this question will help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638205/whats-the-difference-between-tr-and-s-when-using-regex-in-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subroutine:

```
sub complement {

    my ($seq) = @_;

    $seq =~ tr/ACGTacgt/TGCAtgca/;

    return $seq;
}
```

And call it like:

```
my $complemented_string = complement($string);
```

Comment: Neither the `sub`, not the misplaced `scalar` or the `reverse` is relevant here, only the `tr///` operator.

Comment: Note that `scalar $seq` is effectively a no-op. You probably meant `scalar reverse ...`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that one! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You should present your problem as plainly as possible. Asking for a solution that uses a regular expression misleads everyone.

Ever since version 14 of Perl 5, you could use a `/r` modifier on `tr///` to *return* a modified string instead of altering the value in-place. It is probably the best solution if you want to keep both the original and the inverted DNA sequences.

This short program shows an example. Note that `tr///` doe *not* use regular expressions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $seq = 'tcatttcaaatcatctggaccaaaagagtcaggaagt';
my $inv = $seq =~ tr/atcg/tagc/r;

say $seq;
say $inv;
```

**output**

```
tcatttcaaatcatctggaccaaaagagtcaggaagt
agtaaagtttagtagacctggttttctcagtccttca
```

Answer (score 0):

using shell command `tr` directly, if you'd like to try.

```
tr "atcg" "tagc" < file
```