# Perl replace parameter

Tags: perl

I would like to modify a Perl script but I have a problem.

I read the documentation about "tr" command but but my problem is when the string to be replaced is customizable.

For example, my var "$car" contains "&" et I want to replace this string by "\&".

I try this but it doesn't work

```
ligne =~ tr/$car/\$car/
```

Who can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The pattern for [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) gets compiled during compile time. For a dynamic substitution you need to use a regular expression substitution with [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html).

What `tr///` does is called *transliteration*. That means it replaces one character with another character. What you are trying to do is *substitution*, where you want to replace one flexible string with another string. Those are fundamentally different things.

You also need to escape the backslash `\\`. If you put a single one, it'll escape the dollar sign `$`, and replace the content of `$car` with the literal string `'$car'`.

```
$ligne =~ s/$car/\\$car/
```

If you're unsure what is in your `$car`, you should escape it. There could be characters in it that have special meaning in regular expressions, such as `.`. The `\Q ... \E` will escape those so they will be treated as literal characters instead.

```
$ligne =~ s/\Q$car\E/\\$car/
```

Also see [What's the difference between tr/// and s/// when using regex in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3638205/1331451), which is not a direct duplicate.

Comment: Since `$car` contains a caractère and not a regex pattern, one should use `s/\Q$car\E/\\$car/` (or the slower `s/(\Q$car\E)/\\$1/`).